# return an error page from a subthread if the subthread fails

Tags: python, flask

As you can see from my below simplified code/flask app, I am starting a new thread, which calls a sagemaker endpoint, then the old thread redirects to a static page "/completed", which says something like "currently loading". If the sagemaker endpoint works correctly without error, were good to go. But if the sagemaker endpoint doesn't work, I want my flask app to redirect to another page that says something like "error!". Originally I thought I'd need to get back to the original thread from the new thread, but this doesn't seem possible. Are there any recommendations on how I can return an error page from a sub thread inside a flask app? I'm really trying to stay within the Flask framework, and avoid using a bunch of JS.
Please note, I can not simply join the threads with

```
sm_ep.join()
```

as I want to immediately redirect to the "/completed" page.

```
@/app.route('/get_question', methods = ['POST', 'GET']) 
def post_question():     
    @/copy_current_request_context     
    def ask(questions, sentences):         
        call SM endpoint, perform inference, then write to a folder/return results
        if this code errors, I need to return an "Error" to the UI  

    sm_ep = threading.Thread(target = ask, args=(some params))     
    sm_ep.start()     
    return redirect("/completed")  #this returns to a static page so the user isn't 
                                   #waiting
```

EDIT 1:
I've also looked into flask-executor library but that doesn't seem to solve my problem either

Comment: a static page won't make it. You either need a task queue, and an endpoint URL to observe their status, or a client push (websockets?) with quite a bit of additional footwork to make it work with a simple thread.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any resources to explain how I can achieve this in a simple manner, preferably sticking with pure python?